# Tkinter Scrollbar makes button disappear

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I just wanted to add a scrollbar into my code but it destroys my button.

```
import random
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def passcreate():
    passlen = 16
    pass_chars = "AaBbCcDd" #string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    passw = ''.join(random.choice(pass_chars) for i in range(passlen))
    liste.insert(END, passw)

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()
 
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Edit", command=donothing)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

pw = PanedWindow(orient="vertical")

buton = ttk.Button(pw, text= "BUTTON", command=passcreate)
buton.pack(side = TOP)

liste = Listbox(pw)
liste.pack(side=TOP)

pw.add(liste)
pw.add(buton)
pw.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
pw.configure(sashrelief = RAISED)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

In this code there is no problem (i think so)
but when i want to add this part, my button just disappears

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
liste.config(yscrollcommand= scrollbar.set)
liste.pack(side= "right", fill= Y)
scrollbar.config(command= liste.yview)
```

And I want the code to look like without the scrollbar part

Comment: Your button doesn't disappear. It just moves to the left you can see it when you maximize your window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would not recommend to import a package with `*` This fills up your namespace which can lead to conflicts. So better `import tkiner as tk`

This code should work for you

```
pw = PanedWindow(orient="vertical")

buton = ttk.Button(root, text="BUTTON", command=passcreate)
buton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

liste = Listbox(pw, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
liste.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=liste.yview)

pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
pw.configure(sashrelief=RAISED)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```